# What do maskers really do in SHAP package and fit them to train or test?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, shap

I have been trying to work with the `shap` package. I want to determine the shap values from my logistic regression model. Contrary to the `TreeExplainer`, the `LinearExplainer` requires a so-called masker. What exactly does this masker do and what is the difference between the independent and partition maskers?

Also, I am interested in the important features from the test-set. Do I then fit the masker on the training set or the test set? Below you can see a snippet of code.

````
model = LogisticRegression(random_state = 1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

masker = shap.maskers.Independent(data = X_train)
**or**
masker = shap.maskers.Independent(data = X_test)

explainer = shap.LinearExplainer(model, masker = masker)
shap_val = explainer(X_test)```
````

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Masker class provides a background data to "train" your explainer against. I.e., in:

```
explainer = shap.LinearExplainer(model, masker = masker)
```

you're using background data determined by masker (you may see what data is used by accessing `masker.data` attribute). You may read more about "true to model" or "true to data" explanations [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.16234.pdf) or [here](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/1098).

Given above, calculation-wise you may do both:

```
masker = shap.maskers.Independent(data = X_train)
```

---

or

---

```
masker = shap.maskers.Independent(data = X_test)
explainer = shap.LinearExplainer(model, masker = masker)
```

but conceptually, imo the following makes more sense:

```
masker = shap.maskers.Independent(data = X_train)
explainer = shap.LinearExplainer(model, masker = masker)
```

This is akin usual `train/test` paradigm, where you train your model (and explainer) on train data, and try to predict (and explain) your test data.

---

Unrelated to the question. An alternative to masker, which samples data for you, would be to explicitly provide background that may allow comparing 2 datapoints: a point against which compare, and the point of interest, like in [this](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/notebooks/tabular_examples/tree_based_models/Explaining%20a%20simple%20OR%20function.ipynb) notebook. In such a manner one may find out why 2 seemingly similar datapoints were classified differently.

Comment: Cheers! Makes more sense now.

Comment: I wonder if Shap value from the same model object should be different based on different test data, or should one model has only one shap value?

Comment: @HC_2016 They will be different. You may google for "true to model" or "true to data" discussions on github or check out [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.16234) article